# Running a system command in kdb

Tags: kdb

I am trying to run the command in kdb but it does not work. I knew it may be associated with some special character and I am trying to put the [] to escape but still does not work.

```
system "awk '/^Mem/ {print $2}' <(free -m)"
```

I tried

```
system "awk '/[^]Mem/ {print $2}' <(free -m)"  - not working
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another solution just requires a rearrangement of your expression:

```
q)system"free -m | awk '/^Mem/ {print $2}'"
"25408"
```

**EDIT:**

The reason why your expression is failing from q is because of the shell being used. [This answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/45784/511813) explains the difference between shebang and dash shells. I've added a little test to showcase the difference.

```
coneill5@LPTP1893: [~] $ cat test.sh
#!/bin/bash
awk '/^Mem/ {print $2}' <(free -m)
coneill5@LPTP1893: [~] $ cat test1.sh
#!/bin/sh
awk '/^Mem/ {print $2}' <(free -m)
coneill5@LPTP1893: [~] $ ./test.sh
25408
coneill5@LPTP1893: [~] $ ./test1.sh
./test1.sh: 2: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
```

Comment: thanks , do you know whats wrong with my command?

Comment: I've made an edit to my original response which should explain it.

Comment: Cathals answer was the one you were looking for but as another aside if you wish to use bash instead of sh in your system commands you can do the following `q)system"bash -c 'echo $0'"` returns `"bash"` whereas `q)system"echo $0"` returns `"sh"`

Answer (score 4):

You can avoid a system call as kdb+ can return the physical memory available using `.Q.w[]`

```
q)floor (.Q.w[]`mphy)%1024 xexp 2
28072
\\
$ awk '/^Mem/ {print $2}' <(free -m)
28072
```

Comment: [`.Q.w`](https://code.kx.com/q/ref/dotq/#qw-memory-stats)